# How to connect kubernetes pod server on guest os from host os

Tags: kubernetes, virtualbox, portforwarding

I am testing k8s on ubuntu using virtual box.

I have two nodes, one is master, another is worker node.

I deployed a pod containing nginx server container for test.

I can access the webpage deployed by the pod on master node with commands below

kubectl port-forward nginx-server 8080:80

curl localhost:8080

but I want to open this page on my host os(windows10) using chrome web browser
[image]

This is how I set port-forwading on virtual-box...

Comment: Do you have `kubectl` installed and configured to access this cluster on your Windows host ?

Answer (score 1):

simply answer your question, use `address` args for the kubectl command:

```sh
kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 nginx-server 8080:80
```

here is the explanation:

1. `kubectl port-forward` bind to `localhost` by default
2. the `port forward` for your `virtual box` is bind to `10.100.0.104`
3. `0.0.0.0` will bind the port to both `localhost` and `10.100.0.104`
4. change `0.0.0.0` to `10.100.0.104` will also work for `10.100.0.104` access, but not the `localhost`

and also, when exposing a port, you could use a `NodePort` service: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport